# Configuring webpack and babel to transform rest arguments in a node_modules dependancy

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, webpack, babeljs, ecmascript-5

I'm using webpack and babel to compile my JavaScript to ES5. It's working nicely on my own code, but my library started throwing errors in Internet Explorer browsers when I added [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) as a dependency. The error points to a rest parameter (e.g. `function(...t)`) as the place parsing failed.

The main file in the debug module is ES6 ([and that's not going to change](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/745)) and unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any guidance there on babel configuration for node_modules dependencies.

The CLI output doesn't seem to include anything revealing. The output files are being created, as expected, and they work on modern browsers. It's just that rest parameter I can't get rid of.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? It looks like [@babel/plugin-transform-parameters](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-parameters) should fix the issue, but none of the configuration variations I've tried have had any effect on the debug code.

**Edit:** After a closer look, it seems that the problem may be that babel is doing too much transpiling, rather than not enough. It looks like this bit of code from `node_modules/debug/dist/debug.js` is being transformed into the problematic rest parameter.

IN:

```
        function log() {
          var _console;

          // This hackery is required for IE8/9, where
          // the `console.log` function doesn't have 'apply'
          return (typeof console === "undefined" ? "undefined" : _typeof(console)) === 'object' && console.log && (_console = console).log.apply(_console, arguments);
        }
```

OUT:

```
function(n){e.log=function(...A){return"object"==typeof console&&console.log&&console.log(...A)}
```

I've tried including both my source directory and the debug module as an array:

```
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        test: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), /node_modules\/debug/]
      },
```

I've tried including all `.js` files, but excluding most node_modules sub-directories...

```
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        test: /(\.jsx|\.js)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules\/(?!debug)/
      },
```

Even splitting into multiple rules:

```
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        test: /(\.jsx|\.js)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        test: /node_modules\/debug/
      },
```

[Using a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60871267/configuring-webpack-and-babel-to-transform-rest-arguments-in-a-node-modules-depe#comment107697764_60871267) had the same effect:

```
const shouldExclude = filename => {
  if (/my-project[\\\/]src/.test(filename)) return false;
  if (/my-project[\\\/]test/.test(filename)) return false;
  if (/my-project[\\\/]node_modules[\\\/]debug/.test(filename)) return false;

  return true;
};
...
  module: {
    rules: [{ test: /\.js$/, exclude: shouldExclude, use: ['babel-loader'] }],
  },
```

**Here are the mostly-complete config files, for reference**

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-js-library",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-parameters": "^7.9.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.8.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.9.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^1.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.3",
    "classlist-polyfill": "^1.2.0",
    "debug": "4.1.1",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^6.0.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.42.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "yargs": "^15.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports",
    "transform-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-parameters"
  ]
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const config = {
  mode: 'production,
  entry: __dirname + '/src/index.js',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/lib',
    filename: my-js-library.min.js,
    library: 'MyJsLibrary',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /(\.jsx|\.js)$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /node_modules\/debug/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /(\.jsx|\.js)$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  stats: 'minimal',
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve('./node_modules'), path.resolve('./src')],
    extensions: ['.json', '.js'],
  },
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: There's an issue on their repo where some folks provided information to fix https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/701 have you seen it?

Comment: @DvidSilva I hadn't tried that yet; thanks. Unfortunately, I'm getting the same result with `exclude` as a function. I'll add the code above, for reference.

Comment: I wanted to double-check that the transform plugin was working, so I added `foo = (...bar) => debug(bar[1]);` to my own code. It's being successfully transpiled to `foo=function(){Dr(arguments.length<=1?void 0:arguments[1])}`.

Comment: I took a closer look at the code in `node_modules/debug/dist/debug.js` and now I think that it is being transpiled after all. It seems that the transpiling itself is adding the "rest parameter." I think...

        function log() {
          var _console;

          return (typeof console === "undefined" ? "undefined" : _typeof(console)) === 'object' && console.log && (_console = console).log.apply(_console, arguments);
        }

is being changed to

function(n){e.log=function(...A){return"object"==typeof console&&console.log&&console.log(...A)}

Comment: It seems that there're many issues about debug support in IE 11. I find a [similar thread](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/10707#issuecomment-554203412) and you could refer to it to use `overrides` options to instruct babel to process `debug/**/*.js`. If all the attempts are failed, you could try to downgrade your debug version to 3.x.x to make it compatible with IE 11. For more information, you could refer to [this thread](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/689).

Comment: "many issues about debug support in IE 11" ... you could say that again. It's like a Napoleon complex or something.

Comment: Tahnks @YuZhou . I have tried to use overrides, but I hadn't seen that second thread. After looking at the input and output of debug code more closely, it seems that the file is being processed by babel- it's just outputing code that IE can't handle. So, maybe the `syntax-dynamic-import` plugin in the thread you mentioned will help. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Very vivid metaphor. I have no idea if `@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import` will work. The author of the second thread gave the solution [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/689#issuecomment-468428441). You could try the format in it. Besides, don't hesitate to contact me if you have any updates.